# A good book for short problems

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

What is a good book for problems which can be done without much mathematical background? I don't mean IMO-level, since those questions generally require a fairly big amount of mathematical knowledge, but more like questions along the line of the toughest questions on a kangaroo test, some examples:

*We call a natural number a funny number if it is the smallest of all numbers that have the same sum of their digits. 
For example: 29 is funny, because it is the smallest number of which the sum of its digits is 11.
We add up all funny three-digit numbers.
What is the outcome?*

*Mister Small, Mister Medium and Mister Large are going for a walk. 
Mister Large says: “Funny, how our names are all about lengths, but each of us has 
a wrong name.” The smallest of the three answers: “Yes, that is true”.
What are the names of the  gentlemen from smallest to largest?*

*If you multiply 1, 2, 3, …..up to n (inclusive), the result is $2^{15} \times 3^6 \times 5^3 \times 7^2 \times 11 \times 13$.
Which number is n?*

So **fun** questions like these which aren't too long and can be purely done with a decent mathematical intuition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to peruse this list and see if anything catches your eye a,d it hopefully gives you some ideas on other things to look for.

- Entertaining Math Puzzles, Martin Gardner
- Mathematics, Magic and Mystery, Martin Gardner
- The Colossal Book of Mathematics, Martin Gardner
- The Last Recreations, Martin Gardner
- More Perplexing Puzzles and Tantalizing Teasers, MARTIN AUTOR GARDNER
- Classic Brainteasers, MARTIN AUTOR GARDNER
- The Moscow Puzzles, Boris A. Kordemsky
- Logic Puzs to Bend Yr Brain, Kurt Smith
- More Mathematical Puzzles of Sam Loyd
- Challenging Logic Puzzles, Barry R. Clarke
- Second Scientific American Book of Mathematical Puzzles and Diversions
- Hard-To-Solve Math Puzzles, Derrick Niederman
- A Passion for Mathematics, Clifford A. Pickover
- Problem Solving Through Recreational Mathematics, Bonnie Averbach and Orin Chein
- The Ultimate Book of Puzzles, Mathematical Diversions, and Brainteasers, Erwin Brecher
- 25 Real Life Math Investigations That Will Astound Teachers and Students by Edward Zaccaro
- 50 Mathematical Puzzles and Problems Green Collection by Gilles Cohen (Editor)
- 50 Mathematical Puzzles and Problems Orange Collection by Gilles Cohen (Editor)
- 50 Mathematical Puzzles and Problems Red Collection by Gilles Cohen (Editor)
- A Moscow Math Circle: Week-by-week Problem Sets by Sergey Dorichenko
- Chinese Brain Twisters by Baifang
- Challenging Critical Thinking Puzzles by Michael A. DiSpezio
- Great Critical Thinking Puzzles, by Michael A. DiSpezio
- Problem Solving Through Recreational Mathematics by Bonnie Averbach, Orin Chei

You might also like to explore [*Enjoying Math - Learning Problem Solving with Fun Math Puzzles*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Enjoying_Math_-_Learning_Problem_Solving_with_Fun_Math_Puzzles)

Regards

Comment: Awesome! simply awesome! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! I have always wondered if the OP got anything out of it.

Comment: It's a list worth bookmarking! (I wish we could favorite answers like we can for questions!)

Comment: That would be an excellent feature. I often have a difficult time (maybe I am awful at using the search) even finding old answers of mine because I want to reuse something from them.

Comment: @Amzoti Very late,  but yes I did.